# Django cannot locate static files for the index page of the website

Tags: django, static

So, in my index page located in `root/templates/home.html` I have the following line for loading CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'project/home.css' %}">
```

`home.css` is located at:  `root/static/project/home.css`

In `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_ROOT = "static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And when I run the server, in the main page CSS fails to load raising 404 in the browser although the browser displaying the correct path where the `home.css` is located:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/project/home.css
```

For all apps in the projects everything works fine.

When global static is defined in `settings.py`:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

the problem is solved, but then, for obvious reasons I cannot perform `collectstatic` unless I rename it to "assets" for example.

I am clearly missing something here but I want to know why it fails to load the `home.css` from the legit path?

Comment: You can set `STATIC_ROOT` to `STATIC_ROOT='assets/'` and thus collect the static files in `assets`.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I will go with it

Comment: STATIC_ROOT needs to be absolute, as per [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#static-root).